# R Shiny: conditionalPanel not working if used in different tabs

Tags: r, shiny

I would need multiple tabs in my interface, and in each of them I would like to use conditionalPanel. As you will see with the reproducible code here below, the conditionalPanel works in the first tab, but not in the other tabs.

```
ui <- pageWithSidebar(
headerPanel("Hello !"),
sidebarPanel(
tabsetPanel(
tabPanel("a", 
textInput(inputId = "A1", label = "1:", value = "A1"),             
checkboxInput(inputId = "new_A2",
label = "Add another one",
value = FALSE),

conditionalPanel(
condition = "input.new_A2 == true",
textInput(inputId = "A2", label = "2:", value = "A2")
)),
tabPanel("b", 
textInput(inputId = "B1", label = "1:", value = "C1"),
checkboxInput(inputId = "new_B2",
label = "Add another one",
value = FALSE),

conditionalPanel(
condition = "input.new_B2 == true",

textInput(inputId = "B2", label = "2:", value = "C2")     
)
)
)
),

mainPanel()
)

server <- function(input,output){  
}

runApp(list(ui=ui,server=server))
```

I know there are many questions related to conditionalPanel, but I haven't found the answer to this one yet.

Thank you in advance, any suggestion highly appreciated

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Give your tabset panel an id for example `tabsetPanel(id="tabs"` and add the condition when the tab "b" is focused `input.tabs == 'b'`

For example in your 2nd conditional panel the condition will be :

`condition = "input.tabs == 'b' & input.new_B2 == true"`

Comment: It does not work for shiny  version 0.12.2.9007. how to check items belonging to input? such as input$tabs in shiny? Thank you.

Comment: It seems in the new version. `input.tabs == 'b' & ` should be deleted, which means the original works.

Answer (score 0):

with condtional panel, in order to check conditional expression of checkboxinput, we should use 1 instead of TRUE.

ref: [Shiny App checkboxInput and conditionalPanel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34115076/shiny-app-checkboxinput-and-conditionalpanel)

Comment: Welcome to SO. This seems more like a comment than an answer; Have a look at [answer] for guidance. Some context may be helpful for example: The documentation for checkboxInput {shiny} states: "value: Initial value (TRUE or FALSE)." Presumably the function can also take 1 or 0. Or are you saying that TRUE or FALSE do not work? Did you investigate this.